# Regarding Bravais lattices

Tags: material-science, crystals

There is 'End-Centered' Orthorhombic lattice . Why this type is not in 'Cubic' lattice ? On which basis did Bravais propose his theory ?

Answer (score 1):

For first part of question, "Why this type is not in 'Cubic' lattice": quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthorhombic_crystal_system),

> Orthorhombic lattices result from stretching a cubic lattice along two of its orthogonal pairs by two different factors, resulting in a rectangular prism...

So, it's not Cubic because it's stretched from cubic lattice, i.e. lattice constants are different in different directions.

---

**Clarification to answer comment**

If you try to make a base-centered cubic lattice, you'll get some problems:

1. Cubic lattice has 3 rotation axes of order 4, two of which would be removed, thus making a lattice non-cubic
2. There exists another type of lattice with such properties as "end-centered cubic": [tetragonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragonal_crystal_system).

You can see tetragonal lattice if you rotate your plane with cube bases by $45^\circ$.

Comment: I meant to ask ; why Base Centered (also called as 'End-centered') type is not found in Cubic system? Cubic system consists Simple cube , Face-centered cube & Body-centered ; while Orthorhombic has one another subtype ( i.e. Base-centered)  along with these three mentioned. This fourth subtype has particles only on two opposite faces. Why "Base-centered cube" doesn't exist?

Comment: @Chaitanya That is because certain configurations are degenerate. They break down into one of the other bravais lattices. For example, if you have end-centered cubic lattice, it is equivalent to looking at a tetragonal variant from another point of view and hence is a tetragonal lattice rather than the cubic lattice we proposed. Bravais showed that all space filling collection of equivalent lattice points must conform to one of the bravais lattices mathematically using group theory. Hope this helps.